# Where to look for the current patch version installed?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-2

I was reading the [Masseffect.wikia Planet Scanning article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Scanning#Scanning_Tips) and found this tip:

> Patch your game. Before you begin mining, make sure that you have patch 1.02 or higher as it reduces the time required for mining by providing a larger scan area.

I did not find the current version number anywhere in the game setting, where should I look? By the way, I bought the game on Steam, I thought it is supposed to be patched automatically, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find your version number, you will need to run the ME2 Launcher.

To reach the ME2 Launcher with the Steam version installed, find the location on your hard-drive where Steam is installed, then `Steamapps->Common->Mass Effect 2->Binaries`. This is the same location you will need to go to in order [to import your save from ME1](http://social.bioware.com/forum/topic/106/index/840754).

For Non-Steam installs, the launcher should be the Start Menu shortcut created during installation, or it is accessible at the location you installed the game.

Once you have the launcher running (either Steam or non-Steam), [the Technical FAQ](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/106/index/6861142/1)  says to select Configure and choose the Game tab. The number next to `MassEffect2.exe` is your patch level.

Additional info:
Each installed Game in your Steam library has an individual setting for whether or not it should be kept up to date. You can verify that this option is selected for Mass Effect by right-clicking on the entry in your Library, then choosing Properties. On the Updates tab there is a check box entitled "Always keep this game up to date".

Comment: It is set, but how could I confirm the current installed version?

Comment: Took some googling, but I found a link that is more useful than a 2 year old forum post with the same question, or a search result that pointed me back to this thread.

Comment: OK, I also had to access this launcher manually to import my ME1 character. It's in Steam->Steamapps->Common->Mass Effect 2->Binaries. http://social.bioware.com/forum/topic/106/index/840754

Comment: Awesome, integrated that info into the answer. Now The Google will have a good destination for people with this question.

Comment: To start the launcher in Steam, right click the game in the menu and choose "Mass Effect 2 Launcher". Presto!